# How to use multiprocessing.Pool for functions that can't be pickled

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pickle

I would like to use a function for multiprocessing purposes, but it cannot be pickled. Here's what the code fundamentally looks like:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def g(x):
  def g1(y):
    return x*y
  return g1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    f=g(5)
    Pool(2).map(f,[2,3])
```

But when I run the code, I get the errors:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 251, in map
    return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 558, in get
    raise self._value
cPickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'function'>: attribute lookup 
    __builtin__.function failed
```

I have read that `copy_reg` can fix the problem, but the examples are confusing to me. Also, some of them use additional packages like `marshal`. Can someone please provide a simple fix, using `copy_reg` only, if possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use copy_reg for exactly this purpose. copy_reg.pickle() takes a type, and a function as arguments and it then it uses that function to pickle that type of object. In other words it can be used to define functions to use for pickling objects created from a given class. Here is the example from the documentation:

```
>>> import copy_reg, copy, pickle
>>> class C(object):
...     def __init__(self, a):
...         self.a = a
...
>>> def pickle_c(c):
...     print("pickling a C instance...")
...     return C, (c.a,)
...
>>> copy_reg.pickle(C, pickle_c)
>>> c = C(1)
>>> d = copy.copy(c)
pickling a C instance...
>>> p = pickle.dumps(c)
pickling a C instance...
```

Never fear however. The problem you are trying to solve already has a solution. There is a library called pathos that contains a class called ProcessingPool which does exactly what you want. You just need to type this a the command line:

```
pip install -U pathos
```

You can now use pathos instead of mulitprocessing.Pool

```
from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessingPool

def g(x):
    return lambda y: print(x*y)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    f = g(5)
    ProcessingPool(2).map(f, [2, 3])
```

Comment: Cool, pathos. Thanks!